# Extracting coordinates of nearest point

Tags: qgis, proximity

Is there a way in QGIS to extract the coordinates of the nearest point on a polygon from an input point layer? I am looking for the coordinates not the distance, as provided by NNJoin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using the Field Calculator.
Considering that the expression

```
(closest_point($geometry,
aggregate(
'point',
'collect',
$geometry)))
```

will calculate the closest point between your point layer and the polygon layer, you can use this expression in the Field Calculator to create a new field in the polygon attribute table

```
x(closest_point($geometry,
aggregate(
'point',
'collect',
$geometry)))
 || ', ' || 
y(closest_point($geometry,
aggregate(
'point',
'collect',
$geometry)))
```

where the part `|| ', ' ||` is the delimitator between the two values.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, much appreciated!